# How do I draw an ellipse based on focal-point coordinates using svg path?

Tags: html, svg, geometry

I have the coordinates of the focal points of an ellipse.
The distance from one focal-point to the border of the elipse to the second focal-point equals 130% of the total distance between the axis.
http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp
How do I draw an ellipse based on those coordinates using svg? Or any non horizontal elipse for that matter. Unfortenately, I can't use the svg Ellipse in this case.

the following two eliptical arcs form an ellipse, but I have no idea how I should manipulate them based on the focal points.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
     <path d="M 125,75 a180,50 100 1,1 100,50" />
     <path d="M 125,75 a180,50 100 0,0 100,50" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is a follow-up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831363/draw-an-eliptical-line-on-a-coordinate-system-based-on-focla-points, right?

Comment: Yes, I decided to ask a new question. I felt like this information was different entirely and of a more mathematical nature than the previous one. Let me know if you disagree :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two focal points by themselves do not define an ellipse, you'll need one more real parameter. This can be seen from the fact that one can draw an ellipse by wrapping a string *of fixed length* around the focal points and keeping it taunt with the drawing pen. It's that string length you're missing. So you'll need e.g. one point on the ellipse, or something similar.

Given one more parameter and the distance between the foci, you can [compute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#In_Euclidean_geometry) all other parameters like the lengths of the semimajor and semiminor axis, as you require them for your path specification. So for example, if you have one point which should lie on the ellipse, then you could compute the distance to the two foci, add those lengths, and know that sum to be equal to 2*a*, where *a* is the length of the semimajor axis. Then you get the length of the semiminor axis as *b* = sqrt(*a*<sup>2</sup> - *f* <sup>2</sup>), where 2*f* is the distance between your foci.

*Now that you have included the 130% part in your question, I can give you a computation for that as well.*
You have *a* = 1.3 *f*. From that you get *b* = sqrt(1.3<sup>2</sup> - 1)*f* ≈ 0.83 *f*. Notice that *f* still refers to *half* the distance between the focal points. You'll also need to compute two points on the ellipse. It's easiest to choose these on the major axis. So if *F* and *G* are your focal points, then you have *P* = (*f* − *a*)/(2*f*) × *F* + (*f* + *a*)/(2*f*) × *G* as one point on the ellipse, and *Q* = (*f* + *a*)/(2*f*) × *F* + (*f* - *a*)/(2*f*) × *G* as the other.

Once you have the lengths of the semimajor and semiminor axis, you can use these as the radii arguments to the [arc command](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) of an svg path, which are the first two parameters, `180,50` in your example. You can compute the rotation from the slope of the line connecting the foci, using `atan2` or similar, and use that as the third parameter instead of `100`. Set the large-arc flag any way you like (e.g. 0), and the sweep flag arbitrarily but equal for the two halfs of the ellipse (e.g. 0). All these terms refer to the [description](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) in the SVG 1.1 specification. Move to *P*, do an arc with the parameters I just described to point *Q*, and another arc back to *P*.

The result should be a complete ellipse matching your parameters.
*The combination of two arcs was written in a later edit.*

Comment: Oh, right, I forgon about that. The length of the "string" should be 130% of the distance between the focalpoints. The coordinate-system I'm using is on a google map and I will get the focal-points from two clicks on that map. I could probably sort this out based on your instructions, but I'll update the question and would much appriciate some details.